# What's a request for google search for hours?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to make a request to Google and get all results for the last hour or day and etc. You can find the additional instrument panel after any request of searching in the end. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the daterange: search operator. Example:

```
java daterange:2455332-2455334
```

The drawback is that you have to use julian formatted time. Here is a helpful converter: http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm